# s3 SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN error for static site

Tags: amazon-s3

wanted to enable https on my subdomain, with static site hosting.

Some how s3 throws up : 
a.example.com uses an invalid certificate. The certificate is only valid for the following names: *.s3.amazonaws.com, s3.amazonaws.com. error Code : SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

Answer (score 0):

S3 doesn't directly support SSL with a custom domain name on a static web site.  This feature is provided by CloudFront, which you configure in front of the S3 bucket.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-cloudfront-walkthrough.html

After configuring CloudFront, you then need to go to Amazon Certificate Manager, ensure that the selected region is us-east-1¹ and either obtain a new SSL certficate, or import the certificate you purchased from a third party vendor.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs.html

Then, configure the CloudFront distribution to use the certificate from ACM.

---

¹ *us-east-1.* Because of the internal design of CloudFront's integration with ACM, you always select us-east-1 in Amazon Certificate Manager regardless of the region where your S3 bucket is located.  This does not have any pricing or performance implications.